# Can you have a non-constant rational function with degree 0?

Tags: functions

Say f=g/h and f is a stable rational function.

If g and h have the same degree, does it follow that f must be a constant function?

Comment: What is meant by stable?  And over what domain?

Comment: @Tavish: Wouldn’t $f$ be constant if $g=kh$? for any $k\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Loobear23 Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: How do you define "degree" in the case of a rational function ? Usually, it is only defined for polynomials.